# Retrieving current user's profile picture throws "Access Denied" error

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest, csom

I'm trying to get the current user's profile picture and I'm using CSOM.

But I receive an `Access Denied` error, when I actually gave `Read` permission to user profile service.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetCurrentUser, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

});

function GetCurrentUser() {

    var userProfileProperties;
    var deferred = $.Deferred(function () {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);
        userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();
        context.load(userProfileProperties, 'DisplayName', 'Email');
        context.executeQueryAsync(function () { deferred.resolve(userProfileProperties) }, function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args) });
    });

    deferred.done(function (userProfileProperties) {

        var userName = userProfileProperties.get_displayName();
        var email = userProfileProperties.get_email();
        var picUrl = QS('SPHostUrl') + "/" + _spPageContextInfo.layoutsUrl + "/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=" + email;
        $('#userimage').attr('src', picUrl);
        $('#username').text(userName);
    });

    deferred.fail(function (sender, args) {

        console.log('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that my solution will cure your **Access Denied** problem. You have written many lines of code to do this. I have an easy way to do this. Just make a GET request to any following `URLs`.

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/PictureUrl
```

OR

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl
```

I can see that you `DisplayName` and `Email` also. So your final `URL` should look like following

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl,DisplayName,Email
```

You full code should look like following if you are developing SharePoint Hosted app.

Based on our skype conversation, I found that you missed the `jQuery(document).ready`. So update your code as below

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    GetCurrentUser();

    function GetCurrentUser() {
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl,DisplayName,Email",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var userName = data.d.DisplayName;
                var email = data.d.Email;
                var picUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;
                $('#userimage').attr('src', picUrl);
                $('#username').text(userName);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Make sure your app has enough permission to read `UserProfiles`. I have following permission and I am getting result

[image]

Comment: I get nothing, no picture and no error either

Comment: HTML                                                                                                  <img id="userimage" alt="" src="" />
    <div id="username"></div>

Comment: Does your current user have profile picture?

Comment: Yes of course i've a profile picture

Comment: I do not get the user name either

Comment: what does data.d return? Show your full code

Comment: I can not see when I put a breakpoint on the line so feel Visual Studio not of preakpoint

Comment: use console.log(data)

Comment: SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetCurrentUser,'SP.UserProfiles.js');
function GetCurrentUser() {$.ajax({ url:_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl,DisplayName,Email", type: "GET", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",},success: function(data) {var userName = data.d.DisplayName;var email = data.d.Email;var picUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;$('#userimage').attr('src', picUrl);$('#username').text(userName);}, error: function(error) {
               alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: i get nothing on console.log(data)

Comment: I have tested it in my lab and getting result. Check your permission

Comment: I put the same permissions as you but still get nothing
would you help me via skype?? I'd appreciate that I am very much :)

Comment: ok add me in your skype du.atish@outlook.com

Comment: Add me quickly. I have to sleep. It is 1 am in my time

Comment: Going to sleep. See you tomorrow